# How to set up my own CSS and HTML in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have created a login.component.ts like this

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:'',
    templateUrl:'./html/login.html',
    styleUrls:['./resources/css/reset.css','./resources/css/style.css','./resources/css/invalid.css']
})

export class LoginComponent{
    constructor(){
        this.loginImagePath = './app/resources/images/';
    }
    OnInit(){

    }
}
```

and this is my app.component.ts

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent {  }
```

And this is my login.html

```html
    <body id="login">

        <div id="login-wrapper" class="png_bg">
            <div id="login-top">

                <h1>Simpla Admin</h1>
                <!-- Logo (221px width) -->
                <img id="logo" [src]="loginImagePath +'logo.png'" alt="Simpla Admin logo" />
            </div> <!-- End #logn-top -->

            <div id="login-content">

                <form action="index.html">

                    <div class="notification information png_bg">
                        <div>
                            Just click "Sign In". No password needed.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <p>
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input class="text-input" type="text" />
                    </p>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <p>
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input class="text-input" type="password" />
                    </p>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <p id="remember-password">
                        <input type="checkbox" />Remember me
                    </p>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <p>
                        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Sign In" />
                    </p>

                </form>
            </div> <!-- End #login-content -->

        </div> <!-- End #login-wrapper -->

  </body>
```

[image: This is what I am getting as an output]
[image: This is the view]
But the view should be like this 
[image]

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This will make your bottom part expand to fill the entire screen:

```css
.png_bg {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.png_bg > * {
  flex-grow:0;
}
#login-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

If you plan on reusing this layout for other pages, you might consider using some classes for the top and bottom parts and adjust your selectors to match those.
Assuming you'll place `.top_bg` and `.body_bg` on them, you might want to place this into your app's `.scss`:

```css
.png_bg {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  .top_bg {
    flex-grow: 0;
    /* might consider adding a `min-height` to it, too */
  }
  .body_bg {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.But did you notice that , I am getting two body tag one with layout page which will be used in every page  and another is login page body tag with id="login" .but when I remove the body tag from my layout page ,angular automatically render body tag.I am bit confused.

Comment: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2378982/02441c7d1cd5ea55c47f0fce1861356d
This came after edit of your css

Comment: I can't find any reference of my CSS in what you linked, @Pradiptadas. And the layout you linked above is completely messed up. Mostly because of `tutorial.css`. You have elements hardcoded to a width of `4600px`. What are you expecting with rules like that? And if you modified it meanwhile, that's why you should create a [mcve] of your problem. From where I see it, either you or someone in your team has major issues grasping the very basics of CSS. They need to be either stopped or brought up to speed fast if you want your this project to be production ready anytime soon.

Comment: @Pradiptadas, you can see my `scss` [working here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/5sdpkymn/). If you want a solution for your case, you need to reproduce your case here, in a snippet. As in, provide an example that reproduces your layout and link all resources that affect it.

Comment: yes you are right , But basically its not an issue of CSS ,Its an issue of angular2 with HTML from my side , I am just a beginner of angular2 .So I am asking any angular expert to go through my code ,and tell me did i miss something or did anything wrong ?

Comment: All the web is `HTML` + `CSS` + `JS`. Angular2 parses whatever you provide in your `scss` files. I use Angular2. You should check the contents of your `tutorial.scss`, that's where most of the problem is.